# consulta en sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

hola estoy elaborando un proyecto en vb.net y en un combobox tengo listados los meses del año, y en una base de datos de access una tabla con un listado de operaciones, la consulta que me gustaria hacer es que al seleccionar un mes del combobox se busque en el campo fecha solo los registros que corresponden a ese mes solamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola ya he resuelto el codigo quedo de la siguiente manera:
declaro una variable que almacene el mes seleccionado y le sumo uno porque el combobox empieza en cero
sql2 = ComboBox2.SelectedIndex + +1
luego lo uso para ejecutar la consulta y me arroja la informacion que estoy deseando.
sql = "SELECT * from historial where month(fecha)= '" & sql2 & "' "

Answer (score 0):

nos ayudaría que colocaras un poco mas de código en tu pregunta, pero imaginando un poco puedes crear un evento en el combobox tipo `miCombo.SelectedIndexChanged` y realizar la consulta con el id del mes de tu combo. Editaré una respuesta mas completa cuando agregues fragmentos de tu consulta.

Si tienes dudas consulta.

**EDIT**

Respondiendo a tu duda por la consulta sería algo como lo siguiente:

```
Private sub miCombo (Byval sender as system.object,Byval e as System.EventArgs ) handles micombo.SelectedIndexChanged
Dim sql as String = "Select * from tablaOperaciones where MONTH =" & micombo.SelectedIndex  & " and YEAR = " & otroCombo.SelectedItem

End Sub
```

Dentro de todo, igual deberías agregar el año, dado que si consultas solo por el mes (por ejemplo) Octubre (index = 10) te traerá octubre de todos los años que estén registrados.

Marca si te sirve la respuesta.

Comment: bueno es que aun no tengo codigo porque no se como hacerlo la verdad, es precisamente en el selecteditem donde va el codigo, almaceno el mes en una variable y luego hacer una consulta con un select, no se como hacer la consulta select donde le pase el nombre del mes esta lo busque el la columna fecha de la tabla de la base de datos, no se si me explico.... solo lo uq enecesito es como quedaria la consulta select

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para explicar mejor el código

Comment: hola, gracias es asi lo que quiero la cosa es que la columna de la tabla se llama FECHA y guarda valores tipo fecha con el formato 24/04/2019, la cosa es que la consulta queda "SELECT * FROM historial WHERE MONTH ='3'", como le indico que debe buscar en la columna fecha?

Comment: "SELECT ColumnaFecha FROM historial WHERE MONTH ='3'" donde columna fecha es el nombre de tu columna.

Comment: Hola disculpa la tardanza, pero aun sigo sin conseguir la consulta, me da error no such function: Month